# Reactjs - routing for pages, subpages and multiple language handling

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am new to reactjs, trying to build an application that has

- pages
- subpages
- 2 languages.
  so the router.js looks like this

//router.js

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/:langURL/services' component={Services} />
    <Route path='/:langURL/dienstleistungen' component={Services} />
    <Route path='/services' component={Services} />
</Switch>
```

^ so this will invoke 3 pages

```
/en/services
/de/dienstleistungen
/services
```

Inside the services.js contain the subpage routes logic - now is this correct? So essentially if a subpage exists these components get shown.

//services.js

```
return (
  <div>
    <Route path='/:langURL/dienstleistungen/:subPage' render={props => 
    <ServiceIntro {...props} lang={lang} />} />
    <Route path='/:langURL/services/:subPage' component={ServiceIntro} />
    <HowTiles lang={lang} />
     <CarouselTiles lang={lang} />
  </div>
)
```

The problem I am having here is doing a switch between the English subpage/German subpage -- should I just keep adding to the router.js?

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/:langURL/services' component={Services} />
    <Route path='/:langURL/services/page1' component={Services} />    
    <Route path='/:langURL/services/page2' component={Services} />
    <Route path='/:langURL/dienstleistungen' component={Services} />
    <Route path='/:langURL/dienstleistungen/page1' component={Services} />
    <Route path='/:langURL/dienstleistungen/page2' component={Services} />
    <Route path='/services' component={Services} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected though -- it doesn't map to the same subpage for the language settings -- eg.. need to feed in the two language variants for the same page in the footer

Comment: Is this the correct way of going about this? -- Should the routes be part of a nested array structure that then generates route paths?

Comment: I need to try and detect the current language at the route.js -- then provide the footer with both url flavours for the current page